# aws lambda list-functions filter out function name based on layer ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

I just want to get back a list of function names based on Layer Name or ARN

This will give me list of ARN

```
 aws lambda list-functions --query 'Functions[].Layers[*]'
```

How to filter our lambda function name based on the Layer ARN. Means Give me all function name which has the Layer ARN **X**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do here, use the awscli [filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html), for example:

```
aws lambda list-functions \
    --query 'Functions[].Layers[?Arn==`arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1234:layer:MyLayerX:1`]'
```